# How do I effectively concat consecutive interval of strings from ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, stringbuilder

Say I've got an `ArrayList<String>` of size 500 and then I want to effectively concat strings with indexes (starting from 1): 1-100, 101-200, ..., 401-500 strings (so I want to get 5 strings instead of 500). I thought I could use `StringBuilder` and then use `.toString` but `.toString()` method of `StringBuilder` creates a new string, so effectively I'll create `5 * 2 = 10` strings which is bad (these strings are really huge and I'm short of space). What is the most best memory & time efficient way to do this?

**What I've tried so far**:

There's a typo: I meant `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. I used a `StringBuilder` with a straightforward `for` loop over this `ArrayList<String>`. So I used 3x space (1x - for initial `ArrayList`, 2x - for `StringBuilder`, 3x - when call `sb.toString()` which effectively create a returns `new String(value, 0, count);`)

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` to efficiently partially build a `String`. You can tell it an initial buffer size if you have this information already at hand.

Comment: Can you show us a code example of what you are doing? Will be easier to understand then.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is still the best way to do this.  Any other algorithm is going to be equivalent to the same thing.  (Don't use `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder`.)

Comment: There's a typo: I meant `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. I used a `StringBuilder` with a straightforward `for` loop over this `ArrayList<String>`. So I used 3x space (1x - for initial `ArrayList`, 2x - for `StringBuilder`, 3x - when call `sb.toString()` which effectively create a returns `new String(value, 0, count);`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use `List#subList` (as that's just a view of the `List` and shouldn't use any more memory).  You can then call `String#join` on it:

```
String.join(" " /*Delimiter*/, list.subList(0, 100 /*Exclusive*/));
```

Just throw this inside of a for-loop and store each `String` to an index of a `String[]` and you're good to go!

---

By popular demand, here's an alternate solution that is *potentially* more efficient, but would have to be properly bench-marked with JMH:

```
String[] strings = new String[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    List<String> subList = list.subList(100 * i, 100 * (i + 1));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(subList.stream().mapToInt(String::length).sum());

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        sb.append(subList.get(i));
    }

    strings[i] = sb.toString();
}
```

It can be improved if you know the sum of the lengths of each sub-list ahead of time, or replace the call to `List#stream` with its own for-loop.

Comment: Doesn't subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) { return new SubList(this, fromIndex, toIndex); } create a new object?

Comment: Don’t forget that the JVM’s optimizer might have string building related tricks that may render any elaborated Java side optimization attempt useless or even count-productive. By the way, since your second variant is dealing with list indices manually anyway, it would even work wirthout `subList`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question as Java 8, a more functional solution (not necessarily more efficient):

```
Map<Integer, String> result = IntStream.range(0, 500).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    i -> i / 100,
                    Collectors.mapping(strings::get, Collectors.joining())));
```

Other than the overhead of creating the stream, it should be similar in memory usage to @Jacob's solution since `Collectors.joining()` uses `StringBuilder` internally.